# Using GetStream, can I show a user's actions on his follower's timeline but not on his profile feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I am building a web app where users can post articles. They can also comment, like and share posted articles. Users can follow other users so that they see their activities on their timeline feed.

On their timeline feed, they see the activities of all the users they follow. And just like Facebook, they can access a user's profile page where they see the user's "profile feed". On this feed, they only see this specific user's recent activities.

On a "profile feed", I only want to show some specific actions like "Jack **posted** a new article" or "Jack **shared** this article". I don't want to show activities like "Jack **commented** this article" or "Jack **liked** this article". But I wan't to show all of these activities on the timeline feeds.

After reading the whole docs, I don't see how I could do this. For the timeline feed, I'm good. For the "profile feed", I think I would need to read the user feed, but this feed will include all of the user's activities including comments, likes, etc. Is there a way to read a feed and ask for only specific verbs?

Comment: The solution you added later is what I'd recommend as well. I suggest posting that as the answer to this question as well ;)

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli Ok I'll post this as an answer. And then, using this design, how would it work so that users don't have to follow themselves to see their own actions in their `timeline_aggregated` feed? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48983691/5540707), it should be done automatically with GetStream.io, but I don't see it working on my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I handled this situation :

Have two user feed groups. One `user_profile_actions` for actions that belong on a user's profile and one `user_other_actions` for other actions. This way, when I want to display the user's profile, I read the `user_profile_actions` feed. And when someone decides to follow a user, I will make his `timeline_aggregated` feed follows both user feeds this way:

```
$follows = [
    ['source' => 'timeline_aggregated:peter', 'target' => 'user_profile_actions:jack'],
    ['source' => 'timeline_aggregated:peter', 'target' => 'user_other_actions:jack'],
];

$batcher->followMany($follows);
```